# Same function with const and without - When and why?

Tags: c++, constants

```
T& f() { // some code ... }
const T& f() const { // some code ... }
```

I've seen this a couple of times now (in the introductory book I've been studying thus far). I know that the first const makes the return value const, in other words: unmodifiable. The second const allows that the function can be called for const declared variables as well, I believe.

But why would you have both functions in one and the same class definition? And how does the compiler distinguish between these? I believe that the second f() (with const) can be called for non-const variables as well.

Comment: Hint: the first one allows you to modify whatever `f()` returns, which may be a part of the object `f()` is being called on.

Comment: Second one is not allowed to modify the state of the class that this method is defined in.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-overloading.html

Comment: It might be easier to **read** the info from the object than **provide the means to write it** (e.g. reading/writing a single bit in a data structure) - then the `const` version is fast, while the non-`const` version can write, so their code differs.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> But why would you have both functions in one and the same class definition?

Having both allows you to:

- call the function on a mutable object, and modify the result if you like; and
- call the function on a `const` object, and only look at the result.

With only the first, you couldn't call it on a `const` object. With only the second, you couldn't use it to modify the object it returns a reference to.

> And how does the compiler distinguish between these?

It chooses the `const` overload when the function is called on a `const` object (or via a reference or pointer to `const`). It chooses the other overload otherwise.

> I believe that the second f() (with const) can be called for non-const variables as well.

If that were the only overload, then it could. With both overloads, the non-`const` overload would be selected instead.

Answer (score 13):

*But why would you have both functions in one and the same class definition?*

Sometimes you want to provide different semantics for same operation depending on whether it's being invoked on `const` object OR `non-const` object. Let's take an example of `std::string` class:-

```
char& operator[](int index);
const char& operator[](int index) const;
```

In this case when `operator[]` invoked through `const` object you won't let user to change the content of the string.

```
const std::string str("Hello");
str[1] = 'A';     // You don't want this for const.
```

On the other hand,In case of non-const string you let user to change the content of string. That's why a different overload.

*And how does the compiler distinguish between these?*

Compiler checks whether that method is invoked on `const` object OR `non-const` object and then appropriately call that method.

```
const std::string str("Hello");
cout << str[1];           // Invokes `const` version.

std::string str("Hello");
cout << str[1];           // Invokes non-const version.
```

Answer (score 5):

The first one with no const allows the caller to modify the object, which is in general a member of the class whose method is being called.

The second one, where our host class is in read-only mode, also allows read-only access to its member.

By the default, the non-const version is invoked if it is allowed under the rules of constness.

One of the most common examples of this is with some kind of collection / array type class.

```
class Array
{
   private:
      MyType members[MySize];

   public:
      MyType & operator[]( size_t index );
      const MyType & operator[]( size_t index ) const;
};
```

Assuming they are implemented and that it might be a template or they are concrete types and sizes. I'm demonstrating the const overload.

Now we can have someone using the class. You might want to set a value.

```
Array myArray;
myArray[ 3 ] = myObject;
```

Or you might be only reading it:

```
const Array& myArrayRef = getArrayRef(); // gets it to read
const MyType & myValueRef = myArrayRef[ 3 ];
```

So you see I can use the notation to both set a value and read one.
As with `operator[]`, you can apply this technique to any method.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very nice example in the Qt framework.

Take a look at the [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html) class.

There are two public functions:

```
const uchar* scanLine (int i) const;
uchar* scanLine (int i);
```

The first one is for read access only. The second one is for the case that you want to modify the scan line.

Why is this distinction important?
Because Qt uses [implicit data sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html). This means, QImage does not immediately perform a deep copy if you do something like this:

```
QImage i1, i2;
i1.load("image.bmp");
i2 = i1;                        // i1 and i2 share data
```

Instead, the data is copied only and only if you call a function that actually modifies one of the two images, like the non-const scanLine.

Answer (score 4):

The qualifiers after function call parens apply to the hidden `this` parameter of member functions:

A member function `void Foo::bar()` is sort of like this: `void bar(Foo *this)`. But what happens if the Foo object is `const`?

```
struct Foo {
    void bar();
};

const Foo f{};
f.bar();
```

Well, since `Foo::bar()` takes a `Foo *this` parameter, which is not allowed to be `const`, the above `f.bar();` fails to compile. So we need a way to qualify the hidden `this` parameter, and the way C++ choose to do that is to allow those qualifiers to go outside the function parens.

The way the compiler distinguishes these functions is identical in every way to regular function overloading, because that's exactly what it is, despite the weird syntax.

Furthermore, `const` is not the only qualifier. You can also add `volatile` qualifiers, and in C++11 you can also put lvalue and rvalue reference qualifiers.

---

The reason we need two almost identical copies of this function is because there's no direct way to pull out the one single difference: the different return types. If we have a const object, and that object has a getter that returns a reference to something it contains, that reference needs to be qualified the same as the overall object.

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  int &get_i() const { return i; }
};

int main() {
  const Foo f{};
  f.get_i() = 10; // i should be const!
}
```

The above won't even compile because inside `Foo::get_i() const`, `i` is const, and we can't return a non-const reference to it. But if it were allowed, it would be wrong because we shouldn't be able to modify members of a const object. So `Foo::get_i() const` needs to return a const reference to `i`.

```
int const &Foo::get_i() const { return i; }
```

But we *should* be able to modify a member of a non-const object,

```
int main() {
  Foo f{};
  f.get_i() = 10; // should be fine
}
```

so we can't have only this function. We need a function that returns a non-const reference when the Foo object itself is not const. So we overload the function based on the const-ness of the object:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  int const &get_i() const { return i; }
  int &get_i() { return i; }
};
```

If the function body is more complicate there's one possible option to avoid that duplication:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  int const &get_i() const { return i; }

  int &get_i() { return const_cast<int &>(const_cast<Foo const *>(this)->get_i()); }
};
```

That is, the non-const overload delegates its implementation to the const overload, using const_cast to fix up the types. Adding const is always safe. Removing const using a const_cast is only safe when we know for sure that the original object is not const. We do know that in this case, because we know we added the const in the first place to a non-const object.

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to both have access to const instances data in a readonly  way, while still being able to modify non const instances data.

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
  public:
    test() : data_(0) {}

    int& f() { return data_; }
    const int& f() const { return data_ }

  private:
    int data_;
};

int main(void)
{
  const test rock;
  test paper;

  /* we can print both */
  std::cout << rock.f() << std::endl;
  std::cout << paper.f() << std::endl;

  /* but we can modify only the non const one */
  // rock.f() = 21;
  paper.f() = 42;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned before, you can use `const` and non-`const` versions of functions depending on the const-ness of the invoking object. The paradigm is very often used with `operator[]` for arrays. A way to avoid code duplication (taken from Scott Meyers' book Effective C++) is to `const_cast` the `const` function return in a non-const overload, such as:

```
// returns the position of some internal char array in a class Foo
const char& Foo::operator[](std::size_t position) const
{
    return arr[position]; // getter 
}

// we now define the non-const in terms of the const version
char& Foo::operator[](std::size_t position) 
{
    return const_cast<char&>( // cast back to non-const
        static_cast<const Foo&>(*this)[position] // calls const overload
    ); // getter/setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same implementation for both the const and non-const versions of a function without duplicating code, you can use const_cast on the non-const method. Here's an example:

```
struct MyStruct {
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
bool Foo(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    // Implementation for non-const version
    if (!func(1, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { return false; }
    return true;
}

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
bool Foo(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
    // Call the non-const version of the function
    return const_cast<MyStruct*>(this)->Foo(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

};