# c++ standard two different declarations

Tags: c++, function, standards

Why in c++ standard ( I look at cpp reference site) two variants with the same signature are allowed?

For example:

```
reference front();
const_reference front() const;
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters). These are the non-const and const versions of this function. The trailing `const` in the second function changes the signature from the first one.

Comment: relates/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825443/same-function-with-const-and-without-when-and-why

Answer (score 6):

That trailing `const` is part of the signature. Pretend the [implicit `this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) is explicit:

```
reference       front(      This *this);
const_reference front(const This *this);
```

Clearly the argument lists are different.

Comment: It's actually `Type&` or `const Type&`.

Comment: Yes `this` is a pointer but the function parameter takes a reference to the object it is called on.

Comment: Well, there is no function parameter, so we could argue all day about how we want to pretend it may look. My mental model is to treat `this` as an argument to the member function I am using it in. So it must be some kind of pointer.

Comment: @user2079303 You could bind a pointer, reference, or smart pointer.

Comment: I used to think this way. But it cannot explain member functions with ref-qualifiers in C++11.

Comment: @BoBTFish really? I hadn't even though that might be possible. Never mind the noise then.

Comment: I can't find the reference so I could be totally wrong.  I can find what `this` is but not the implicit function parameter.  Could swear it is a reference but  I guess it really doesn't make a difference.

Comment: In the unified call syntax proposal, the alternative member call syntax seems to use a reference: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0251r0.pdf

Comment: Bear in mind `this` existed in the language before references did, and is not specified in any way as an "implicit parameter", just as a magical keyword.

Answer (score 4):

> two variants with the same signature

That's a common misconception. The `const` at the end of the signature *is* part of the signature.

It can be useful, for example, with container classes that return references to the contained data. The `const` version returns a `const` reference so the datum cannot be modified through that reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `const` in the second function counts as part of the signature.

```
const_reference front() const; 
                     // ^^^^^
```