# C++ - Conversion loses qualifiers error

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion loses qualifiers
```

when trying to implement indexing operator without the code duplication (I will show the segment of code):

```
Point* BufferedList::indexTemp(size_t idx)
{
    if (idx >= size) return nullptr;

    return &arr[idx];
}

const Point* BufferedList::operator [](size_t idx) const
{
    return indexTemp(idx);
}
Point* BufferedList::operator [](size_t idx)
{
    return indexTemp(idx);
}
```

However, the following works (this doesn't use the helper function `indexTemp` and it is duplication of code):

```
const Point* BufferedList::operator [](size_t idx) const
{
    if (idx >= size) return nullptr;

    return &arr[idx];
}
Point* BufferedList::operator [](size_t idx)
{
    if (idx >= size) return nullptr;

    return &arr[idx];
}
```

Do I really need two functions for indexing (one that returns `Point*` and the other that returns `const Point*`)?

Comment: in this case I would just use the duplicate code

Comment: There are a million duplicates of this already. Did you search at all? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825443/same-function-with-const-and-without-when-and-why / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537271/why-do-we-need-both-const-and-non-const-getters-in-this-example / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479548/why-having-const-and-non-const-accessors

Answer (score 6):

It is because you call a non `const` function from a `const` function. The compiler warns you that your `const` object will be no more `const` in temp function.

Comment: So... do they really need two functions? Anyway, a duplicate this lazy doesn't need to be answered.